Best practice for multi-platform CI/CD
I am new to CI/CD and I want to create a CI/CD pipeline on gitlab that compiles my code on:

MacOS
Linux x86
Windows

So far, I have been doing it only on Linux using the following strategy:

I use a shared gitlab runner
The gitlab runner pulls a docker image that I have created that has as a base image ubuntu:22.04 and has all the dependencies for my project
The instructions on the .gitlab-ci.yml file are executed and my code is compiled producing the shared library .so that I save as an artifact.

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:
stages:
- docker
- build

build_docker_image:
  stage: docker
  image: docker:20.10.16
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASS
  script:
    - docker build -t "$REGISTRY_USER/my_dependencies:latest" .
    - docker push "$REGISTRY_USER/my_dependencies:latest"
  rules:
    - changes:
        - Dockerfile

build_and_test:
  stage: build  
  image: "$REGISTRY_USER/my_dependencies:latest"
  script:
    - mkdir build
    - cd build
    - cmake ..
    - make 
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/libtest.so
  



Now, i want to produce the shared libraries on MacOs and Windows. If I understood well, I cannot use Docker containers because they cannot use an osx or a windows base image, right ?
I thought of using two virtual machines (osx and windows) and installing beforehand all the dependencies in each one. Is this a correct way ?
Thanks a lot and sorry for any ambiguities in my question, I am new to all this.

If you can find a way to build both the macOS and Windows versions on a Linux machine, that would likely be the simplest solution.
If that is not possible, your only three options are probably:

Use an OSX and Windows Machine (as you mentioned) and install GitLab as Shell-Runner, which is available for both platforms.
Use GitLab's Hosted Runners, which are available both in OSX and Windows Versions.
Experiment with OSX and Windows Containers. There are “workarounds” like dockurr/windows or docker-OSX, but success heavily depends on which OS Functions your code actually uses.


Thanks for your reply. In the end I went for the first option, together with a linux gitlab shared runner using docker
